# Android Convert String to Int Total Sum Digit

Tags: java, android, string, string-concatenation

> I have String A=1   F=8 B=2   G=3 C=3   H=5 D=4   I=1 E=5   J=1
>
> I want input String from textbox to convert to a Int to be sum int.
>   Help me please!

Comment: what do you mean by "sum int"?

Comment: have a switch case of you values send in each char and you get your int value. show what you have tried so far and we can help you.

Comment: I want input Name to enter the keyboard. The value of a character variable A = 1 B = 2 C = 3, So if the input ABC output is equal to 6.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you completely. Please correct me if so. I would say put in all the values in a `HashMap<Character,Integer>` (eg A:1) and so on ... You can then get the values from the character stream inputted and add to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

well this doesn't directly answer your question but from this you can achieve what you want.

If you have a string such as "123", you cannot do math with it, or use it anywhere you could use an integer unless you first convert it to the Java int type.

There are many ways you can do this, but the easiest way is simply use the method Integer.parseInt(). Example:

```
String s = "123";
int i = Integer.parseInt( s );
```

in your case you can convert Strings to to int and keep adding them to a variable;

```
int sum = 0;
sum+Integer.parseInt( A );
sum+Integer.parseInt( B );
sum+Integer.parseInt( C );
sum+Integer.parseInt( D );
sum+Integer.parseInt( E );
sum+Integer.parseInt( F );
sum+Integer.parseInt( J );
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

int sum = Integer.valueOf(A) + Integer.valueOf(B) + Integer.valueOf(C);

if you want to get from textview directly then use this :

Integer.valueOf(textView.getText().toString());